# How to convert boolean pandas dataframe to square matrix dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this (boolean values)

```
a    b    c    d    count
1    0    1    0    196
0    1    0    1    110
0    1    0    0    17
0    0    1    0    10
0    0    0    0     9
```

As you can, someone can be **a** and **c** // or **b** and **d** // or only **c**
I want to built a square matrix dataframe, where

```
   a    b 
a  0    0
b  0    17
c  196  10
d  0   110
```

Can I get something like this? I tried

```
result = df.merge(df, on=['ID']
count = pd.crosstab(df[columns_x],df[columns_y])
```

but it didn't get what I want

***Note***
The main data frame is like:

```
a     b     c     d   
Yes   No    Yes   No   
No    Yes   No    Yes   
No    Yes   No    No 
No    No    Yes   No  
No    No    No    No
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by simply do a dot product.

```
df_transpose = df.transpose()
count = df_transpose.dot(df)
> 
  a     b    c   d
a 222   5    8   1 
b 5     154  14  22 
c 8     14   34  6 
d 1     22   6   29
```